# Alfresco property page default values should not be default in advance search screen

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

In alfresco content model I have made some default values and I can see it on the Alfresco property page in share UI.

I used following tag in content model to make No as a default value.

```
<default>No</default>
```

But the requirement is, it should not be default on advance search screen.
Is it possible to customize this as per my requirement? If yes, then what files need to be changed and how. please share the sample script of possible.

Comment: Any suggestions please

Comment: What kind of field it is? drop-down or text field?. We have built our own custom dropdown with empty value as the default value for the custom drop-down control.

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan I have drop-down list, I have changed it to default in the content model and it's coming over property page, but I don't want it as a default in advance search. can you please share your views

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan where you made custom drop-down, In advance search screen or in the property page?

Comment: We added the drop-down in our own advance search page, but it is for our custom content type.

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan you mean that you have default value in the content type, but on advance search it's not default as it's a custom drop-down. If this is the case then please share some code samples with required file changes as a answer. It will be really helpful. Thanks in Advance.